# Using awk to calculate negative exponents

Tags: awk

I'm using awk to scale a number but awk gives an incorrect answer. Take for example:
VALUE=-565 and SCALE=10E-3

```
awk -v a=-565 -v b=10E-3 'BEGIN { print (a * b) } '
Answer: -5.65
```

Which is wrong.

If i use ^ instead of E i get:

```
awk -v a=-565 -v b=10^-3 'BEGIN { print (a * b) } '
Answer: -5650
```

Which is also wrong.

However if i change 10E-3 to 0.001 i get the correct answer:

```
awk -v a=-565 -v b=0.001 'BEGIN { print (a * b) } '
Answer: -0.565
```

I tried forcing awk to print a floating point but i still get a wrong answer:

```
awk -v a=-565 -v b=10E-3 'BEGIN { printf "%f\n", (a * b) } '
Answer: -5.650000
```

Any idea why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 3):

10e-3 is 0.01, not 0.001, so the answer it correct

```
In [12]: 10e-3 == 10 * 10**-3 == 0.01                                           
Out[12]: True
```

Comment: According to: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E-3) 10^−3 = 0.001

Comment: Right, but 10e-3 ,is 10 * 10^-3, not 10^-3

Comment: Ah yes that is true so that result is correct. What is wrong with the line where i use 10^-3 then?

Comment: When you say `-v b=10^-3`, `b` is taken to be a string --- awk doesn't know to "eval" it as a snippet of code.  When awk finds a string in the context of a numeric operation it just uses the digits up until the first character that can't be part of the number, which is `10` in this case. You would get the same answer with `-v b=10giraffe`

Comment: @jas Alright i didn't know that. Changed all my scales to decimal form from exponents. Is there any way to come around that limitation in awk?

Comment: Don't you just want to do this, which works fine? `awk -v a=-565 -v b=1E-3 'BEGIN { print (a * b) }'`